# Clean up yaml data during build in Middleman

Tags: ruby, yaml, middleman

I have some data in a yaml file. I want to calculate some values from this data, which I’ll then use in pages built from a template. So far I’ve been doing this sort of calculation in helpers but it involves a lot of repetition (e.g. the same calculation is made multiple times for one page) and is really a misuse of helpers.

I’m looking for an alternative, better way of doing this. What I’d like to do is at build time process the data file and do the calculations once so that the results can just be read (as many times as necessary) when I build the pages.

In my config.rb file I envisage something like:

```
#call some code here to process data.products here, either overwriting the products.yml or creating a new file such as products_cleaned.yml

#this code already exists...
data.products.each do |p|
    proxy product.url, "/product.html", locals: { product: p}, ignore: true
end
```

What’s the best way to do this? Do I need to write an extension, or is there another way I can call some ruby to munge my yaml file? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to generate yaml from external data and what I did was have a separate script that would generate yaml data files for me. Then I would use something like `make` or `rake` to sequence the two calls to this script and `middleman build`. Then my generated yaml was visible from the config.rb file.

If you didn't want to add a build step then another thing you could do is process the data.products file and just create ruby hash structures yourself from it. If you are generating yaml then you can use ruby yaml libaries to parse this to hashes (http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych.html). Then you can pass these to the proxy call. Something like

```
#call some code here to process data.products here
my_products = Psych.load(process_products_to_yaml_string(data.products))

#this code already exists...
my_products.each do |p|
    proxy p.url, "/product.html", locals: { product: p}, ignore: true
end
```

Comment: Thanks Gerard for the tips. After asking my question I ended up just writing a ruby module and passing that the product objects to process. Beside the original <at>local_data object, Middleman then automatically creates a <at>local_data_enhanced object containing my amended product. I think this is the same as your second solution...